# Can I use PluginSettings for saving repository level settings in Bitbucket plugin?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I am developing a plugin for Bitbucket and I am adding a couple of settings at the repository level.

Can I use PluginSettings to save the data at the repository level or is PluginSettings used only for Global settings?

Also, I have a very small data to be saved. Probably one table. Is PluginSettings the way to go or should I use Active Objects?

Please let me know your thoughts and experiences with both.

Thanks,
Kaushik

Comment: I have read that Active Objects is preferred in general but when the database is too small, PluginSettings could be the way to go. Do you agree with that?

Comment: I'd suggest asking this on answers.atlassian.com, a more active community exists there for Bitbucket add-on development

Comment: @Rog Thanks for the input. I did ask there on answers.atlassian.com website. I didn't get any response. Most of the time the website is down for maintenance issues. So, just wanted to try my luck here.

Comment: Oh, that's no good. Sorry about that, I'll get someone to take a look.

Comment: I have figured out my solution for this problem @Rog. I went with PluginSettings and it worked. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose to go with PluginSettings and it proved to be much easier than Active Objects. I was able to achieve my goal to save plugin data on the server side with PluginSettings. FYI.